# Best way to push data to connected users from .NET web application

Tags: c#, .net, rest, signalr, data-stream

the scenario is the following :

-We have a MVC web application with an in-memory database providing users with a set of features.
-We created a REST web api in that application that an android application consumes to provide the same services to mobile users.

Given that we also have data that are frequently updated (live soccer) ,what is the best way to send updates to all connected mobile devides ?

These data are fed to the application through an external api and users of the web application are notified using SignalR clients.I guess we probably need a data streaming service that utilizes sockets ,but which one available is best suited for the given scenario and the technologies used ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: How are you hosting your solution? Is it cloud or on-premise? Because both can use different techs.

Comment: It is a dedicated server with Windows Server ,so we can configure it any way we want .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your mobile app to either poll or maintain a dedicated connection because both drain the battery, you should use android's dedicated push mechanism ("Firebase Cloud Messaging", formerly "Google Cloud Messaging").

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Comment: What if its IOS or Microsoft phone?

Comment: Windows phones are out of life soon, but there is [Windows Push Notification Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview). iOS has [Apple Push Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)